# Refactoring Rails acts_as_votable gem Into Services

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, service, acts-as-votable

I'm in the process of cleaning up controllers for a rails 5 app and I've created a service to flag posts. Unfortunately, since moving the acts_as_votable helper methods into a service, none of the flags are working. Any thoughts why this isn't working?

app/services/flag_service.rb

```
class FlagService
  def initialize(params)
    @current_user = params[:current_user]
    @post = params[:post]
  end

  def process
    if previous_vote?
      @post.vote_by :voter => @current_user, :vote_scope => 'flag'
    elsif !previous_vote?
      @post.unvote_by @current_user, :vote_scope => 'flag'
    else
      nil
    end
  end

  private
    def previous_vote?
      @current_user.voted_for? @post, vote_scope: 'flag'
    end
end
```

app/controllers/bursts_controller.rb

```
...
  def flag
    if FlagService.new({current_user: current_user, post: @post}).process
      render(status: 201, json: @category.as_json({:only => [:id, :status, :name, :description, :slug, :title] }))
    else
      render(status: 400, json: @category.errors)
    end
  end
...
```

Comment: is voted_for? working if you call it in the controller directly? Can you try that?

Comment: Write a unit test which tests `FlagService` seperatly. You should also change the arguments to be either positional `def initialize(user, flaggable)` or required keyword args `def initialize(user:, flaggable:)` as they should be non-optional since the service does not work without them.

Comment: @Niklas yep; that works in the controller. It also appears to work in the service, but any updates to Votes are not persisted.

Comment: I can't really see why you have three conditions either - as the third `else` condition will never be reached.

Comment: Maybe I'm tired, but I think if your current_user has a previous vote on a post, you want to unvote it? Because if you have a previous vote, you vote again with the current user, which should not change anything?

Comment: @Niklas actually it looks like i'm the one who's tired. you are correct; it was a syntax error. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # ...
  def flagged?(post)
    voted_for? post, vote_scope: 'flag'
  end
end
```

---

```
class FlagService

  def initialize(user:, post:)
    @user= user
    @post = post
  end

  def process
    if @user.flagged?(@post)
      @post.unvote_by @user, vote_scope: 'flag'
    else
      @post.vote_by voter: @user, vote_scope: 'flag'
    end
  end
end
```

Given how little actual code is involved I would question why this should be extracted to a service since it adds an additional level of abstraction. Instead you may want to create seperate routes to flag/unflag that respond to `POST` and `DELETE`.